# Instalar mysql-python en Windows

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, windows

¿Qué pasos debo seguir para instalar correctamente mysql-python en mi sistema operativo Windows?

Comment: se que no es una pregunta pero no sabia como hacerlo y muchos puede que esten igual: pueden bajar lo necesario de sus lugares originales por si me borran el archivo:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Comment: Hola Gerardo, creo que sería mejor opción plantearas la pregunta y escribieras  posteriormente la respuesta, tal vez sería muy útil y buen aporte, más aún si no se tiene en el sitio en inglés de SO.

Comment: Hola Gerardo, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo que muevas todo el texto que tienes acá a una respuesta y cambies el texto de ahora a algo tan simple como: "¿Cómo configurar Python para trabajar con MySQL?" o "Integrar Python con MySQL ¿Por qué obtengo el error X?" o algo similar. De lo contrario, no será una pregunta válida, a pesar que el aporte tenga buen contenido, porque no cumple con el formato del sitio.

Comment: @Gerardo93 La comunidad crece con este tipo de aportes, pero te invitamos a que dividas el texto en pregunta y respuesta, ya que asi es mas facil econtrarlo para otros usuarios y tu contenido sera mejor valorador :D

Comment: Buen aporte, cuando lo dividas como te recomiendan arriba voto positivo :)

Answer (score 2):

Para instalar `mysql-python` en Windows:

Primero, hay que tener instalado wheel, esto pueden lograrlo de la siguiente manera:

```
pip install wheel
```

Luego en el directorio donde este descomprimido MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip copiar los archivos `.whl` y despues hacer en la consola y ubicado en el directorio de la descomprension:

para la [versión de Windows de 32 bits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5):

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

para la [versión de Windows de 64 bits](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python):

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

---

P.D. Para aquellos que les marca error y ya tienen instalado el compilador de c++ para python 2.7, en este enlace pueden bajarlo de nuevo.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: No funciona este enlace:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266
Saludos y gracias.